# Trying to shoot video with my Nikon coolpix p510 while plugged in

Tags: nikon, coolpix

I know the USB ac square and cable it comes with wont allow this to happen. I ordered a Nikon EH-62A AC Adapter, it looks to be more substantial, does anyone know if this will solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual, this should work.

Excerpt from manual:

[image: instructions on inserting fake battery]